# How to create a calculated row in sql or power bi?

Tags: mysql, sql, powerbi

I am trying to do a **calculation** on 2 rows on a SQL I wrote so I can have a **3 row** that will be Profit and show the amount is it **possible**?

This dummy data not true to any company!

see below :

```
SELECT a.pcg_type GL_Acoount_Group,
     Abs(sum(b.debit-b.credit)) GL_Amount
FROM dolibarr.llx_accounting_account a
JOIN dolibarr.llx_accounting_bookkeeping b
  ON a.account_number = b.numero_compte
WHERE a.pcg_type IN ('INCOME', 'EXPENSE')
    ANDa.fk_pcg_version = 'PCG99-BASE'
GROUP BY a.pcg_type
```

***Results:***

Group.       Amt

INCOME     379200

EXPENSE    65700

***Expected Results:***

Group.       Amt

INCOME     379200

EXPENSE    65700

PROFIT     313500

Comment: what will be your expected result?

Comment: i now added the expected results

Comment: If you define the query as a CTE, then you can use `UNION` to add the extra row. You can also create a view for this purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use ROLLUP for adding an extra row and use CASE statement inside SUM() function for treating expense value as negative for calculation

```
--MySQL
SELECT COALESCE(acc_type, 'Profit') "Group"
     , ABS(SUM(CASE WHEN acc_type = 'EXPENSE' THEN -amount ELSE amount END)) amt
FROM test
GROUP BY acc_type WITH ROLLUP
```

Another way by using UNION ALL

```
SELECT acc_type "Group"
     , SUM(amount) Amt
FROM test
GROUP BY acc_type

UNION ALL

SELECT 'Profit' AS "Group"
     , SUM(CASE WHEN acc_type = 'EXPENSE' THEN -amount ELSE amount END) Amt
FROM test
```

Please check this url https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f859036ffcb3d808330bce5346daee1e